# Remove all text between (and including) a forward-slash and a comma

Tags: sed, regular-expression, cut

I have a .txt document that contains thousands of strings all with a similar layout, but some of the lines have additional info I do not want.

Here’s an example:

```
202212_08,ABC123/A1234,AB,,C123
202212_08,CDEF1233/A5678,FG,,C345
```

I would like the the output to be as:

```
20221208,ABC123,C123
20221208,CDEF1233,C344
```

I have tried using regular expressions, but I keep getting an error and the output is empty. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I formatted your code, is that actually your output and desired output? Because in the `edit` section there were two lines but in the final output both lines were in a same line

Comment: Hi, each line should be on their own. Not in one line. I’m not sure why it posted like that. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, then that's the actual output. When you want to add another text line you should use `<br>`. Or in this case I gave a format by using **back-ticks**

Comment: Appreciated, thank you

Comment: Regarding your question, it seems the second field always have the forward-slash `/`. Or are there other fields/columns whose can have `/`? For example, can you have a line like this: `202212_08,ABC123/A1234,AB,,C1/23` ? Note that at the end I have `C1/23` should that field be considered too?

Comment: Hi, the / only appears in column 2, and it is not always there, but sometimes it is. 
When it is present, that’s when i need the data to be removed. 
Thank you

Comment: The [cas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727707/414186) is good and solves your problem, you should try it and if you get the desired result then mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 's:/.*,:,:' input.txt 
202212_08,ABC123,C123
202212_08,CDEF1233,C345
```

This replaces everything from the first `/` seen in the line to the last `,` in the line with a single `,` character.

---

However, it's generally better to use awk or perl when your input data contains multiple fields, as they allow you to manipulate and/or print each field individually.

For example, the following awk script removes `/.*` from the second field of each input line using the `sub()` built-in function, then prints the first (`$1`), second (`$2`), and last (`$NF`) fields.

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '{sub(/\/.*/,"",$2); print $1, $2, $NF}' input.txt 
202212_08,ABC123,C123
202212_08,CDEF1233,C345
```

or with perl:

```
$ perl -F, -lane '$F[1] =~ s:/.*::; print join(",",@F[0,1,-1])' input.txt 
202212_08,ABC123,C123
202212_08,CDEF1233,C345
```

The `-F,` option sets the field separator (similar to awk), and the `-a` option causes the input to be automatically split into an array called `@F`.  `-l` turns on perl's automatic handling of line-endings (e.g. newline or `\n`) and `-n` makes perl work like `sed -n`. `-e` tells perl that the next argument is a script to execute.

Note that perl array indices start from zero, not one, so `$F[1]` is the second element of the `@F` array, and the array slice `@F[0,1,-1]` is the first, second, and last element of the array.

Comment: Amazing thank you! This worked perfectly. 
Follow on question, how could I remove the same extra characters when the /A…,, is not there. Here’s the example:

Comment: 202212_08, ABC1234,AB,,C123    Should be output as:  202212_08, ABC1234,C123

Comment: @Brendan just for clarification, when you post an answer/question, giving a format is valid but when you leave comments you're limited to a few format, such as **bold**,*italic*, `highlight lines`.. (you can press the `Help` button to see an example)

Comment: if the second column doesn't contain a `/` then the `sub()` function (awk) and `s///` operation (perl) will do nothing to that field.

Comment: Great, understood thank you